# Selenium - Element Not Visible Error - Periodic Occurrence

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am writing Selenium tests in Java to test a simple PHP web application. Much of it involves filling out fields.

If I try to run the test twice (or more) in a row, I get the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 

Session ID: ef10680c-429b-4312-9d69-41496e7dce6a
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at com.midamcorp.insurance.TesterNGTest.test(TesterNGTest.java:83)
```

The statement is correct the element is not visible - the problem is why it is not visible. At the start this element is hidden by Javascript. However, showing it is as simple as clicking a link element. I perform this "click" in my test as well.

```
 @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C://geckodriver/geckodriver.exe");
       driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
     driver.get(BASE);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }


    @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {

      // login 

    driver.findElement(By.id("ssn")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ssn")).sendKeys("user");
    driver.findElement(By.id("user")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("user")).sendKeys("pass");
    driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();

    // insurance screen

     driver.findElement(By.name("phone")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("phone")).sendKeys("phone");
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("email");
    driver.findElement(By.id("empSSN")).sendKeys("ssn");
    driver.findElement(By.id("address")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("address")).sendKeys("address");
    driver.findElement(By.id("city")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("city")).sendKeys("city");
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("state"))).selectByVisibleText("Missouri");
    driver.findElement(By.id("zip")).sendKeys("63780");
    driver.findElement(By.id("genderFemale")).click();

if(!(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox")).isSelected())) { driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox")).click(); }
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='1']")).click();
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("employmentLocation"))).selectByVisibleText("Central Office");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.btn.btn-primary")).click();



    // enrollment 

             // the code below is supposed to see if the container for the radio buttons is hidden, if so, click the link to display them

    if( !(driver.findElement(By.id("healthOnly")).isDisplayed()) ) {
              driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='#healthOnly']")).click();
    } 


    // the line below is the one that throws the error; the link noted above is not being clicked and thus the container with the radio buttons remains hidden

      List<WebElement> insuranceOptions = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#healthOnly input[type='radio']"));
         insuranceOptions.get(rand.nextInt(insuranceOptions.size() - 1)).click();

         insuranceOptions = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[name='visionID']"));
         insuranceOptions.get(rand.nextInt(insuranceOptions.size() - 1)).click();
```

My simple Javascript/jQuery function to show and hide the element. It works as expected when I click it manually.

```
$(".insuranceOptionsToggle").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $($(this).attr("href")).toggle();   
 $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need a short wait to give the element a chance to become visible.

BTW, you don't want to use that jQuery function to unhide the element because no user is going to use that function to unhide the element. Automate only what a user can and would do.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new to Selenium, but I thought the call to implicitlyWait would have prevented this? Also, it is probably not clear from my post, but the .insuranceOptionsToggle element being clicked (a link) is always visible (so it is actually the function called during normal user interaction). Clicking that link unhides a div element that houses radio buttons. It is the div that is not always displaying. Thanks again.

Comment: I can't find information to prove this but I think implicit wait may just wait for presence of the element and not visibility. I think the fact that you are getting a `ElementNotVisibleException` and not a `NoSuchElementException` shows this. You could use a `WebDriverWait` and wait for visibility here and see if that fixes the issue. NOTE: Don't use implicit and explicit waits together, it will give you unreliable results per the docs. http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp